# CSS cases for smartphones and tables

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, css, web-applications

Dear stackoverflow community,

to create responsive design in the past, it was quite easy to use @media with min-width and max-width to define the design proportions.Now we have smartphones and tablets with large screen revolutions such as 1080p (1920 x 1080 pixels) on most of all recent android based smartphones and tablets. iOS is popular on +720p screen resolutions.

In fact most of all desktop resolutions are comparable now with smartphones and tablets, I can't find a easy way to make a distinction of cases in css.

Do you know a good guide to realize this without using a CMS or excessive pre-build template?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you want to tell the devices apart?

Comment: Because I want to have a page width of 70% width on the PC browser and on all mobile devices a 100% full width.

Comment: [Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that page and it doesn't helps. How can I use 70% page width on a PC but on 100% on a 1080p device (1920 x 1080 or 1080 x 1920 pixels), such as smartphones, tablets, TVs, etc.?

Comment: Even by using the DPI amount as a workaround won't work either.
`@media only screen
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (min-resolution: 192dpi)
{
#outerWrap {
 width: 100%; 
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

This javascript code adds a class to the body element if you have a touch device or not. This helped me a lot and makes it realy easy to seperate between mobile and desktop devices.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //detect if browser supports touch
    var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;
    if(is_touch_device){
        $('body').addClass('touchDevice');
    }else{
        $('body').addClass('notTouch');
    };
</script>
```